# There is no extension able to load the configuration for "when@test"

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem on my symfony project **version 4.4.9**, when i type php bin/console make:entity this errors it display to me

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "when@test"

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1.3",
    "ext-ctype": "*",
    "ext-iconv": "*",
    "doctrine/annotations": "^1.13",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.2",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.11",
    "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*",
    "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
    "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
},
```

**PHP 7**
[image]

Comment: I believe you may need to register an extension https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/bundles/extension.html

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message you are facing and your attempts to resolve the problem. According to https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-configure-multiple-environments-in-a-single-file, `when@test` is only available on Symfony 5.3 and later

Answer (score 1):

The syntax when@{env} was introduced on Symfony ^5.3
You need to downgrade the doctrine-bundle to a compatible version that works with Symfony ^4.4.

Answer (score -1):

problem solved :
i delete this part of code from config>packages>doctrine.yaml  :

when@test:
doctrine:
dbal:
# "TEST_TOKEN" is typically set by ParaTest
dbname_suffix: '_test%env(default::TEST_TOKEN)%'

when@prod:
doctrine:
orm:
auto_generate_proxy_classes: false
query_cache_driver:
type: pool
pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
result_cache_driver:
type: pool
pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool

```
framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.app
            doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.system
```

Comment: For the record, that configuration syntax was [introduced in 5.3](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-configure-multiple-environments-in-a-single-file).